# Custom "Post Author" Input Instead of Dropdown

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a site with over 20,000 users. Occasionally I need to update the author of a post. However, the sheer amount of users makes the "Author" metabox on the edit post screen unusable. I'm trying to make a custom box where I can input the desired author's ID and change the post author to that ID. Ideally, I would like to do this within the box itself, rather than by way of saving/updating the post.

Here's my custom meta box code:

```
//Get the post data
$id = get_the_ID();
$author_id= $post->post_author;

<div class="update-author">
    <p><strong>Current Author ID:</strong> <?php echo $author_id;?></p>
    <p><strong>CHANGE AUTHOR ID TO:</strong></p>
    <form id="update-author-form" method="post" action="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url('admin-post.php') ); ?>" >
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update_author_form">
        <input type="hidden" name="post-id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
        <input type="number" id="update-author-id" name="update-author-id" value="" />
        <button id="update-author-button" class="button button-primary button-large">Update Author ID</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Next, I have my form function built as follows:

```
function handle_update_author_form() {
        
        $post_id = $_POST['post-id'];
    
        $update_id = $_POST['update-author-id'];
    
        $my_post = array(
            'ID'            => $post_id,
            'post_author'   => $update)_id,
        );
        wp_update_post( $my_post );
         
    }
```

At this stage, my form button does nothing but refresh the page and send it to the posts screen (I know, I need to change the redirect URL).

Comment: I would go for another approach of just removing the original metabox and replacing it totally with a new metabox...

Answer (score 0):

Like in comments - I would go for a another approach of removing the original meta_box and replacing it with a new one - **or alternatively just use a JS to turn the dropdown list into a searchable field** ( for example the excellent [select2](https://select2.org/dropdown) plugins - but have others - and also pure JS is quite easy - **see example below** )

Anyhow - in your code that you posted you are missing the [hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/) where you can apply and invoke your code, for example:

```
'add_action( 'save_post', 'handle_update_author_form', 10, 1 ); '
```

Have a look at wp [filters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference) and [actions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference).

**The suggested (simple) JS solution :**

Now, for the simple approach of just using `JS` to pseudo-search inside the dropdown and therefor there is no real need to interfere with the query or post injections.....

**myPlugin.php / myTHeme,php**

```
function admin_enqueue_scripts_callback(){
// We are using select2.js from CDN here ..

    //This will add Select2 CSS 
    wp_enqueue_style( 'select2-css', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css', array(), '4.1.0-rc.0');

    ////This will add Select2 JS
    wp_enqueue_script( 'select2-js', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js', 'jquery', '4.1.0-rc.0');

    // Now we need a JavaScript file to initialize the Select2 elements
    // here it is staged as a plugin - but a theme would be the same .
    
    wp_enqueue_script( 'select2-init', '/wp-content/plugins/select2-init.js', 'jquery', '4.1.0-rc.0');

}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_enqueue_scripts_callback' );
```

**select2-init.js**

```
// initialize select2 on author dropdown field with jQuery

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#post_author_override').select2();
});
```

**voilà !**

At this point you will have the pseudo-search implemented that would resolve your problem in a practical way without any new `->queries` or `$objects` and with minimum coding.

**Possible / potential caveats**

I am not sure what would be the efficiency of filtering 20,000 items.
It would be interesting to know how the select2 JS would perform with such a long list...

But if it is already loaded to the DOM i guess it would be ok ( might take a few seconds to react though )

Please let me know how it performing if you implement the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the insight into using select2. I do like your solution. I implemented it and the search function is nice, and definitely more elegant than the simple dropdown. Performance wise, it's pretty rough with the amount of users on the site. At best it takes several seconds to generate the dropdown. Worst case, it hangs up requires a page refresh. I can use this to make the dropdown navigable, but I'll still keep working on an alternative to input user ID directly.

Comment: @GDailey - I understand that a long list could be a trouble. But you can be a bit creative and add another small filter ( checkbox, radio ? ) also for the user ROLE ( or first letter or anything else that comes to mind according to situation ) 
Of course It will not help if ALL your users have the same role - But the direction of pre-filtering the list can also help..